# Size of the HTML page for all screens

Tags: html, css

I am new to web designing. I had just build a web page but now it is not looking accurate as it was built.

Right Now i have just built a container with:

```
#container {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border:4px solid green;
}
```

**Question:** How do I fix the `height` & `width` of the page for all screens & sizes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: No question, no answer. ;) (How about giving `height` and `width` ___specific___ values?)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0
}
.container
{ 
    width:auto; /*Since div is block element, it takes automatic full width*/
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
    border:4px solid green;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DTU3W/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Having height:100%; plus a 4px border will always exceed the height of the page, and will cause scroll bars to appear at all times